# VtC as Off Topic needs a new category

Tags: discussion

An option to Vote-to-Close of "Is not about Windows Phone operating system" might be useful.

See [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/led-monitor-problems-while-connected-to-notebook-with-os-windows-8-1) question as an example.

Answer (score 1):

We could reword and generalise the close reason:

> Questions about the Windows Mobile operating system are off-topic here as it is a completely separate platform from Windows Phone. See: Is Windows Mobile on-topic?

Perhaps something like:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic unless they directly involve tools related to connecting to Windows Phone devices. You may be able to get help on Super User.